# Angular proxy.conf.js modify response from server

Tags: angular, proxy, reverse-proxy

I need some Angular `proxy.conf.js` help.

I would like to transform the response object coming from my back-end E.g. (wrap the server response in a `{ data: ... }`), as the `dev`one is different to the one in `prod`.

Is this possible? I have been trying to use `bypass` but no luck.

The closest I have gotten to was to use `res.write('data')`, but that seems to **pre-pend** data to the response rather than modify.

```
{
    context: ['/app/request'],
    target: 'https://tst.my-website.com',
    bypass: (req, res) => {
      // Do something with res to transform the response
    },
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    changeOrigin: true,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here:

https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/97#issuecomment-423257695

Specifically, this comment:

```js
const zlib = require('zlib');

onProxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
    let originalBody = new Buffer('');
    proxyRes.on('data', function (data) {
        originalBody = Buffer.concat([originalBody, data]);
    });
    proxyRes.on('end', function () {
        const bodyString = zlib.gunzipSync(originalBody).toString('utf8')
        const objectToModify = JSON.parse(bodyString)
        objectToModify.modification = 'Mickey Mouse'
        res.end(JSON.stringify(objectToModify));
    });
},
selfHandleResponse: true // necessary to avoid res.end being called automatically
```